# Create a new column based on max of column with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame like the following:

```
 GROUP OGS valMax
1 Group1 A   81.5
2 Group1 B   87.1
3 Group1 C   66.2
4 Group2 D   7.2
5 Group2 E   5.3
6 Group2 F   10.1
```

I am trying to create new column "groupMax" by filling it with max of "valMax". The expected output is:

```
  GROUP OGS valMax groupMax
1 Group1 A   81.5  87.1
2 Group1 B   87.1  87.1
3 Group1 C   66.2  87.1
4 Group2 D   7.2   10.1
5 Group2 E   5.3   10.1
6 Group2 F   10.1  10.1
```

I did the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
df %>% group_by(GROUP) %>% mutate(groupMax = max(valMax))
```

The error I get is,

> Error in mutate(groupMax = max(valMax)) : object 'valMax' not found

Is the data masking not working here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `groupby` should be `group_by`. Apart from that your code looks correct. Are you sure column is called `valMax` ? What does `names(valMax)` return?

Comment: Please share your data in [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (like a `dput`) so we can just copy/paste it for testing. Something doesn't seem right about what you posted. You should have got a different error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ronak suggests:
You can `group_by` GROUP and then mutate a new variable `groupMax`with `max()`function

```
library(dplyr)

# your data
df <- tribble(

  ~GROUP, ~OGS, ~valMax,
"Group1", "A", 81.5, 
"Group1", "B", 87.1, 
"Group1", "C", 66.2, 
"Group2", "D", 7.2, 
"Group2", "E", 5.3, 
"Group2", "F", 10.1)

df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(GROUP) %>% 
  mutate(groupMax = max(valMax))
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this what the OP was already doing? Do you think the problem was using `groupby` rather than `group_by`? Shouldn't have have given a different error message? Or are you assuming `groupby` was another function that was defined in the global workspace?

Comment: @ MrFlick. Yes you are right `groupby` was the problem. I saw the desired output and started to solve. I recognized it after I posted my answer. Should I delete the answer?

Comment: Yes. I mixed it with pandas and made a typo. Also, in my end, I got the pipe-symbol wrong. Instead of %>%, it read %%.